# C# - How to send and read Post array of JSON data to WCF RESTful Service

Tags: c#, json, wcf, post

My concerns:

1. Is my below code correct? for the input being sent.
2. I am try to debug locally with SOAPUI and POST MAN , my function is being hit but the input is null - So I want to know - how to send a http post request with JSON data?

URL I am trying:
http://localhost:49240/TranslationService.svc/DVRDatalist

Type: JSON(application/json)
Raw data:

```
{"DVRMigration":"[{“ProgramID”:”1111”,”ServiceID”:”1111”,”ChannelNo”:”11”,”TimeSlot”:”1111”},{“ProgramID”:”2222”,”ServiceID”:”2222”,”ChannelNo”:”22”,”TimeSlot”:”2222”},{“ProgramID”:”3333”,”ServiceID”:”3333”,”ChannelNo”:”33”,”TimeSlot”:”3333”},{“ProgramID”:”4444”,”ServiceID”:”4444”,”ChannelNo”:”44”,”TimeSlot”:”4444”}]"}
```

3. I need sample code for the below input where that input is saved, and split so that I can perform my DB operations, for ex on:

   `{“ProgramID”:”1111”,”ServiceID”:”1111”,”ChannelNo”:”11”,”TimeSlot”:”1111”}`

   and form a final list and return the response in json

====================

Below is the Sample input that will be sent to the Web Service:

[INPUT] => JSON Data

```
{“DVR Migration”:[{“ProgramID”:”1111”,”ServiceID”:”1111”,”ChannelNo”:”11”,”TimeSlot”:”1111”},{“ProgramID”:”2222”,”ServiceID”:”2222”,”ChannelNo”:”22”,”TimeSlot”:”2222”},{“ProgramID”:”3333”,”ServiceID”:”3333”,”ChannelNo”:”33”,”TimeSlot”:”3333”},{“ProgramID”:”4444”,”ServiceID”:”4444”,”ChannelNo”:”44”,”TimeSlot”:”4444”}]}
```

Below is the sample output I should receive back from Web Service:

[OUTPUT] => JSON Data

```
{"DVR Migration”:[{"ChannelNo”:"11","GuideStart":"00","ProgramID”:"1111","PvrID":"111","SeriesID":"1001","ServiceID":"1234","TableID":"11","Title":"ABCD","UpdateFlag":"False”},{"ChannelNo”:"22","GuideStart":"00","ProgramID”:"2222","PvrID":"111","SeriesID":"1001","ServiceID":"1234","TableID":"11","Title":"ABCD","UpdateFlag":"False”},{"ChannelNo”:"33","GuideStart":"00","ProgramID”:"3333","PvrID":"111","SeriesID":"1001","ServiceID":"1234","TableID":"11","Title":"ABCD","UpdateFlag":"False”},{"ChannelNo”:"44","GuideStart":"00","ProgramID”:"4444","PvrID":"111","SeriesID":"1001","ServiceID":"1234","TableID":"11","Title":"ABCD","UpdateFlag":"False”}]}
```

File name: ITranslationService.cs

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "DVRDatalist", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped)]
[return: MessageParameter(Name = "DVR Data List Migration")]
List<DataList> DVRDatalist(Migration migration);
```

File name: TranslationService.cs

```
public List<DataList> DVRDatalist(Migration migration)
{
    List<DataList> response = new List<DataList>();
    var list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Migration>>(Convert.ToString(migration));
    foreach (var row in list)
    {
        var datalist = new DataList();
        string pgrmId = row.ProgramID;
        string svcid = row.ServiceID;
        string cn = row.ChannelNo;
        string ts = row.TimeSlot;
        string pvrid = row.PvrID;
        string tid = row.TableID;
        DataSet dsdvrdata = dvr.Getdvrdata(pgrmId, svcid, cn, ts, pvrid, tid);
        datalist.ServiceID = dsdvrdata.Tables[0].Rows[0]["ServiceID"].ToString();
        datalist.ProgramID = dsdvrdata.Tables[0].Rows[0]["ProgramID"].ToString();
        datalist.ChannelNo = dsdvrdata.Tables[0].Rows[0]["ChannelNo"].ToString();
        datalist.UpdateFlag = dsdvrdata.Tables[0].Rows[0]["UpdateFlag"].ToString();
        datalist.Title = dsdvrdata.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Title"].ToString();
        datalist.GuideStart = dsdvrdata.Tables[0].Rows[0]["GuideStart"].ToString();
        datalist.SeriesID = dsdvrdata.Tables[0].Rows[0]["SeriesID"].ToString();
        datalist.PvrID = pvrid;
        datalist.TableID = tid;

        response.Add(datalist);
    }
    return response;
}
```

Data Members:

```
public class Migration
{
    //string topstring = string.Empty;
    //List<string>=new List<>;

    public List<DVRMigration> DVRMigration { get; set; }
    public string ChannelNo { get; set; }
    public string ProgramID { get; set; }
    public string PvrID { get; set; }
    public string ServiceID { get; set; }
    public string TableID { get; set; }
    public string TimeSlot { get; set; }
}

public class DVRMigration
{
    public string ServiceID { get; set; }
    public string ProgramID { get; set; }
    public string ChannelNo { get; set; }
    public string TimeSlot { get; set; }
    public string PvrID { get; set; }
    public string TableID { get; set; }
}

public class DataList
{
    #region Properties
    [DataMember(Order = 1)]
    public string ServiceID { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Order = 2)]
    public string ProgramID { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Order = 3)]
    public string ChannelNo { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Order = 4)]
    public string UpdateFlag { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Order = 5)]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Order = 6)]
    public string GuideStart { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Order = 7)]
    public string SeriesID { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Order = 8)]
    public string PvrID { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Order = 9)]
    public string TableID { get; set; }

    #endregion
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you should decorate your desired request/response class (DataList class here for response) with `[DataContract]` attribute as well.

Looking at your code, your action method is expecting a Migration object and you would like to pass a DVR Migration object. In this case, either you should try changing the Action method parameter to DVRMigration or you should pass a Migration object from JSON request to this action method. MVC model binding works by binding incoming request data object with Action parameter. It checks for name and properties compatibilities of these.

Then, you can create a Javascript object named DVRMigration and initialize its properties and send it to controller i.e.

```
var input = { DvrMigration: { ServiceID: 1, ProgramID: 123 and so on} };
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://localhost:49240/TranslationService.svc/DVRDatalist",
    contentType: "application/json",
    data: JSON.stringify(input),
    success: function (result) {
        alert("POST result: " + JSON.stringify(result));
    }
});
```